# Apps deleted from jailbroken iPad after battery died

Tags: ios, jailbreak, ipad

My iPad's battery recently completely died and when I plugged it in all the apps were gone. I've rebooted it and checked iFile and it says all the apps are still there but they don't show.

Answer (score 1):

SSH into your device as the mobile user and run `uicache` then respring.